# Visual Studio 2019 can't load pdb files from microsoft symbol server. What to do?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, symbols, pdb-files

I am trying to open a .dmp file on VS2019. It throws the error message kernelbase.pdb not loaded.

On checking further, it is not able to load any of the PDB files form Microsoft symbol server.

I have already enabled Microsoft Symbol Server under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols

Is there anything else I have to enable in order to load symbols from Microsoft servers?
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQYop.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The issue was that in the Symbol Caching path under Tools->Options->Debugger.
I had given a path for which Visual Studio did not have the permission to write over there. Changed the path to a folder directly under C drive and it started working.